# What styling properties for #root in a react project?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules

I'm relatively new to react and I've been struggling a bit with styling. I was wondering if I it's good to apply any css to #root or if it's best not to do it.

And is it possible to apply styling for #root but only for one component in a module.css file?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Inline CSS**

- Dependencies: None
- Difficulty: Easy
- Approach: Worst

**Regular CSS**

- Dependencies: None
- Difficulty: Easy
- Approach: Okay

**JSS**

- Dependencies: react-jss
- Difficulty: Easy
- Approach: Decent

**Styled-Components**

- Dependencies: styled-components
- Difficulty: Medium
- Approach: Decent

**CSS Modules**

- Dependencies: css-loader
- Difficulty: Tough (Uses Loader Configuration)
- Approach: Better

**Sass & SCSS**

- Dependencies: node-sass
- Difficulty: Easy
- Approach: Best

**Less**

- Dependencies: less, less-loader
- Difficulty: Easy
- Approach: Good

**Stylable**

- Dependencies: stylable, @stylable/webpack-plugin
- Difficulty: Difficult
- Approach: Better

I looked at several ways of styling components in a React application. I then compared and contrasted these methods examining their advantages and disadvantages. Finally, I demonstrated how to use Sass (my preferred method of styling a React application) in a Create React App project.

Sass is a CSS preprocessor, and CSS preprocessors are here to stay. They extend the basic CSS features by providing you with a set of powerful functionalities that will raise your productivity right away. I mentioned a few benefits, but there are many more, like inheritance, functions, control directives, and expressions like if(), for() or while(), data types, interpolation, and so on.

Becoming a Sass guru may take a bit of time; all you need to do is look into the Bootstrap Sass files to see how Sass could turn into a complex thing. But learning the basics and setting it up for your project is something you could start today.